# How to perform something similar to a two way ANOVA when one of the gruops does not fit the normality hypothesis?

Tags: r, anova, normal-distribution

I have a question about basic statistics: I have a set of data divided in four groups, defined by two variables. I ran the normality test (shapiro_test {rstatix}) and one of the groups does not fit the normality hypothesis (p=0.02).

In this case, can I perform a two way ANOVA or should I run another test? In that case, it is the Aligned Rank Transform (ART) ANOVA the best option, and what package and function do you recommend?

Comment: Check out Mann-Whitney test, Wilcoxon test, Friedman test and Kruskal-Wallis test.